# How to solve specific recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations

How would you solve this recurrence relation?

$f_k(a+i b k)=f_{k-1}-f_{k+1}$

$a$ and $b$ are reals and $k$ is an integer in $-\infty$, $+\infty$, $i$ is the imaginary unit.

Comment: This is called a "recurrence relation". But I like how you named it, it's fancy ^^

Comment: thank you! I've changed the title accordingly

Comment: This is not a recurrence relation in the usual sense, because $f_k$ is defined in terms of both $f_{k-1}$ and $f_{k+1}$, with no "initial conditions."  (One obvious solution is $f_k = 0$ for all $k$.)

Comment: It is a recurrence relation, consider that it defines $f_{k+1}$ in terms of $f_k$ and $f_{k-1}$

Comment: See Favard's Theorem ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favard%27s_theorem

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks for the link.  It still seems to require initial conditions.

Comment: Thank you all. Do you think that there is a chance of finding an analytic solution to this problem?

Comment: For what it's worth,  [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f(x%2B1)%3D-(a%2Bi+b+x)f(x)+%2B+f(x-1)) gives a solution in terms of Bessel functions.

Comment: It looks like $f_{k-1} $ and $f_{k+1}$ on the right need an argument.  Please supply them.  Otherwise, they should be constants and this just defines $f_k$ to be a constant.

Comment: No, they are not functions. They are constants that are indexed by the index $k$, which runs from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$. Perhaps I should rewrite the equation above as $(a+i b k)f_k=f_{k-1}-f_{k+1}$ to avoid confusion.